# Generic style for textboxes with Text binding in wpf using Triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datatrigger

I have a requirement in which a TextBox is bound to a property with ViewModel. The default value is -1, but i don't want to show as -1 to user, but as "Default". I have similar kind of Textboxes in many places in my project. So, a style was created and setting the Text property in DataTrigger, but somehow the code wasn't working. 
I am still learning Wpf.

Please help.

The xaml is as follows.

```
<Window x:Class="TextBoxDefaultStyles.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBoxDefaultStyles"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="TextBox"
           x:Key="DefaultStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="-1">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Default"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"
             Style="{StaticResource DefaultStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Text="Dummy"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I want to have the behavior, if the Binding value is -1, then show Default as text or if Binding value is <> -1 then show that text. If a user enters text in the editbox, usually numbers then that has to be updated to the underlying binding.

Comment: Is the property you are binding to a string or some other type?

Comment: You would have to remove the `RelativeSource` from the binding in the DataTrigger. Still it would only set the `Foreground` property, but not replace `Text`. Just use a binding converter instead.

Comment: Is this just a job for `FallbackValue` in the binding base?

Comment: @LeeO. Binding to an integer property type.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do won't work because of the [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx) list used in WPF. `DependencyProperty`s can be set from several different sources, so Microsoft had to devise a list of value precedence... which source should have more precedence?

If you look at the linked page, you will see the Dependency Property Setting Precedence List which shows which sources have precedence over the others. What you're trying to do is overwrite a value that is set by data binding (*Local Value* in the list) with a value that is set by a `Style Trigger`. You should notice that the *`Style Triggers`* entry is much lower in the list than the *Local Value* entry.

That means that it has *less* precedence than the *Local Value* entry and so it will never overwrite the value.

Instead, it is more common to use the [`IValueConverter` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the `-1` value to `Default`.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    return value.ToString() == "-1" ? "Default" : value;
}
```

Comment: +1 for Dependency property value precedence. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this is not working because Local Value has higher precedence that Trigger Value .  [Dependency Property Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Try it using Converter

> xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Stackoverflow.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stackoverflow"
    >
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TextConverter x:Key="textConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Converter=textConverter}"/>
</Grid>
```

> Converter

```
    public class TextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value.ToString() == "-1")
            return "Default";
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: but what about the Foreground property? Do i need to use another converter for checking if Text is Default or actual value.

Comment: Use a trigger for the Foreground property just like in your own example. Instead of checking if Text is -1, check if it is "Default".

Comment: yes for forground use the trigger but In Trigger set Value= Default instead of -1.